# Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, пример действительно кросс-платформенного опенсорсного ПО с GUI, написанного на чистом C?

Tags: linux, c, windows, gui, opensource

Я начинаю разработку программного обеспечения на Си с открытым исходным кодом, и хочу определиться с универсальными GUI библиотеками для таких платформ:

- Linux: GTK-based дистрибутивы,
- Linux: Qt-based дистрибутивы;
- Windows;
- OS X;

Исследования показали, что далеко не всё так гладко с переносом GUI между платформами, а в сети обсуждаются только случаи для C++/Qt и прочей коммерции.

Не так интересен список библиотек/API, как интересно было бы посмотреть на орагнизацию GUI кода в реально существующем кроссплатформенном ПО.

Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: Просто интересно, почему именно C?

Comment: Можно еще рассмотреть wxWidgets. Он полностью опенсорсный. Но хуже поддержка

Comment: @tym32167 Во-первых, потому, то что ненавижу ООП, а во-вторых потому что не знаю языка программирования лучше )))

Comment: @Александр wxWidgets написана на C++, Perl, Python. Хотелось бы что-то нативное, на чистом Си.

Comment: Из чистого C я знаю только ncurses.

Comment: @DennisV.R., ну тогда GTK+. Чистый Си

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если используете чистый С , то кросплатформеность с иcпользованием функций библиотеки  GTK+ , достаточно высокая. Если использовать только функции GTK и Glib , то дефайны ставил только на пути по умолчанию. Ну и сборка проекта была различна.

Comment: хочу уточнить пару тройку вопросов: как обстоят дела с драг-энд-дроп элементов. Например, могу ли я картинку перетягивать из окна в окно в рамках одной программы? Есть ли поддержка у GTK на стороне мобильных платформ? Какую ветку брать для безпроблемного переноса между платформами? Только третью или можно ограничиться второй (не по-душе мне распухлость третьей)))

Comment: @DennisV.R., примеры программ на GTK: GIMP, Monodevelop, некоторые линукс-дистрибутивы на GNOME. ДрагЭндДроп там нормально реализован. Под мобильные GTK нет, насколько знаю. Самое близкое для мобил по вашим запросам - Qt, и то мобильное Qt и Qt под десктопы - абсолютно разные вещи. Из абсолютно кроссплатформенных биб есть Киви, но она под python.

Comment: Спасибо, @Александр. Посмотрю GIMP, т.к. хорошо его знаю как потребитель. Очень достойное решение по качеству кода (с точки зрения конечного пользователя, сырцы не видел) Monodevelop написан на C#, насколько я разузнал.

Comment: @Александр - нормально реализован полный d&d или только простейшие вариации с текстом и с файлами? Есть ли там, например, delayed rendering или поставка данных через IStream?